# Why is it impossible to find natural numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $12b^2=a^2$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

This was a question in the exercises for an [EdX course by Prof Starbird on Effective Thinking through Mathematics](https://courses.edx.org/courses/UTAustinX/UT.9.01x/1T2014) which was long over, but I am working through the course at my own pace.

I feel that the 'correct' answer given by the course is wrong - I do not want to paste it here because it may violate the Course Agreement (even though the course ended 3 months ago).

"Why is it impossible to find natural numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $12b^2=a^2$?"

Can you please look at my reasoning and tell me what is missing?

My attempt:

Assume it is possible to find natural numbers $a$ and $b$ such that $12b^2=a^2$

Then

$$3 = \frac{a^2}{2^2\cdot b^2}$$

Implies that $a^2$ is even. The prime factorization of $a^2$ will contain $2\cdot 2$.

Assume $a = 2\cdot c$ where $c$ is odd.

So
$$3 = \frac{c^2}{b^2}$$

Now $b^2$ is also odd. But it does not mean that the prime factors of $b$ and $c$ contain $3$.
The 'correct' answer seems to assume that the prime factors of $b$ and $c$ contain $3$.
I feel this is incorrect.

Comment: note: the assumption that $a=2*c$ where $c$ is odd is not valid - take $a=8$: $a^2 $ is even but $\frac{a}{2}=4$ is not odd.

Comment: @Ant how did you format to include standard math notation? (I did not see math formatting in Help)

Comment: @likejiujitsu take a look at this http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: @Ant, thanks for the link

Comment: It would be much easier to ask: what is $\sqrt{12b^2}$? The answer is $2b\sqrt{3}$. But it never hurts to step through a basic proof by contradiction, even if another method of proof is better for the task at hand.

Comment: @AlonsodelArte As Jean mentioned, it is a variation on the classical proof that \sqrt{2} is not rational i.e. there is no a,b so that \sqrt{2} = a/b.

Comment: @likejiujitsu And like I said, it doesn't hurt to go through this exercise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's a variation on the classical proof that $\sqrt{2}$ is not rational.

If $12b^2=a^2$, you can assume $a$ and $b$ have no common factor, otherwise you factor them out. Then $3$ divides $a^2$, but $3$ is prime, so it divides $a$. Then $a=3c$, so $12b^2=9c^2$ thus $4b^2=3c^2$, and $3$ divides $b$. Contradiction, so your equation has no solution.

Comment: Or, $12b^2=a^2$ implies $3(2b)^2=a^2$ and $\sqrt 3$ would be rational.

Comment: @lhf That's the essence of my proof, yes, to prove $\sqrt{3}$ is irrational.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut it is easy to understand the classical proof about square root of 2, because 2 is the only even prime. So if a number is even, then its prime factorization must contain 2. However, all the rest of the primes are odd. So an odd number need not have 3 in its prime factorization.

Comment: @likejiujitsu The proof does not rely on parity, but on divisibility by a prime $p$. It works with $2$, $3$ or any other prime, and the same proof will show that $\sqrt{d}$ is irrational unless $d$ is the square of an integer. Because only squares have in their factorization only primes to even powers: it's where parity arises, in powers, like in mathlove's proof, but here it's not necessary as I assume all common factors are already removed, so a prime $p$ must divide at most one of $a$ or $b$.

Answer (score 4):

In your proof, you can set $a=2c$, but note that $c$ may be even. Note that all we know is that $a$ has *at least* one $2$ as its prime factor. (You may miss the case when $b$ is even.)

We can prove the statement in the following way :

For $2^2\cdot 3\cdot b^2=a^2,$ the number of the prime factor $3$ in LHS is *odd* while the number of the prime factor $3$ in RHS is *even*. This is a contradiction. **Q.E.D.**

Comment: how do we know that RHS has 3 as a prime factor?

Comment: @likejiujitsu We know that if it has $3$ has a prime factor, it must have an even power. But it's odd on the left. +1 mathlove

Comment: @likejiujitsu: I didn't say that RHS has $3$ as a prime factor. All I said is that the number of the prime factor $3$ in RHS is *even*. (Note that 0 is even, but again I don't say RHS has no $3$.) We don't need to care about the number of $3$ in my proof.

Comment: @mathlove I still don't understand - you are assuming that 3 is in the RHS. It can be odd without containing 3.

Comment: @likejiujitsu: I'm not assuming that. First, the number of $3$ as prime factor in both sides has to be the same, right? This means that the parity of the number of $3$ in both sides has to be the same, of course. (Do you agree?) However, we know that it is odd in LHS, and that it is even in RHS. This is a contradiction.

Comment: @mathlove "the number of 3 as prime factor in both sides has to be the same". what if 3 is *not* a prime factor in both sides?

Comment: @likejiujitsu: I don't get what you mean. $3$ is prime, so $3$ is always a prime factor.

Comment: @mathlove what if 3 is not a prime factor in a, and also not a prime factor in b?

Comment: @likejiujitsu: In that case, the number of $3$ as a prime factor in LHS is $1$ (note that $1$ is odd), and the number of $3$ in RHS is $0$ (note that $0$ is even). This is a contradiction.

Comment: @mathlove 'contradiction' of what?

Comment: @likejiujitsu: We suppose that there exists a pair $(a,b)$ such that $2^2\cdot 3\cdot a^2=b^2$. Contradiction of this supposition. Hence, we can say that there is no such pair.

Comment: @mathlove Are you saying that an odd number has a unique prime factorization?

Comment: @likejiujitsu: No. I've never said that. I'm just saying that the number of $3$ as a prime factor in LHS is always odd while the number of $3$ in RHS is always even. This fact contradicts that supposition.

Comment: @likejiujitsu: You understand that $a^2$ ($b^2$ also) has even number of $3$ as a prime factor, don't you?

Comment: @mathlove No, I do not understand why it should have 3 as a prime factor at all - it can, but is not required.

Comment: @likejiujitsu: Please note that I don't say that $a^2$ does have at least one $3$ as a prime factor. What I say is that the number of $3$ as a prime factor of $a^2$ is either $0,2,4,6,8,\cdots$, which is even. Of course, $a^2$ may not have any $3$ as a prime factor. But now the most important thing is that the number of $3$ of $a^2$ is *even* because of the form of $a^2$, no matter if $a^2$ has at least one $3$ or not.

Comment: @mathlove I agree with you that **if** 3 is a prime factor of a then there must be even number of 3s in a^2. But that does not mean that b should have 3 as a prime factor at all - unless as I asked above, every number is either prime or has a unique prime factorization.

Comment: @likejiujitsu: If $a$ has no $3$, then $a^2$ has no $3$. Yes, this is true. But it is also true that in this case $a^2$ has even number of $3$ because **$0$ is even**. So, it is true that if $a^2$ has no $3$, then $a^2$ has even number of $3$. Note that the word "even" includes zero.

Comment: @likejiujitsu If a number $A$ is equal to the a product $P\cdot Q$, then I hope you will agree, $P$ divides $A$ and $Q$ divides $A$ (it's merely the definition of "$P$ divides $A$", that $A$ must be the product of $P$ and another number). Here, $3\cdot 4b^2=a^2$, so $3$ divides $a^2$. But then [Euclid's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclid%27s_lemma) guarantees that $3$ divides $a$. Hence, your equation implies that necessarily $3$ divides $a$. Do you agree with this?

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut I agree with you that 3 divides a^2 and 3 divides a.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut ok, I see it now. since 3 divides a^2, it is a prime factor of a but then there are an uneven number of 3s on LHS and RHS.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut if the equation was 3^2 * 2^2 * b^2 = a^2 then we would be able to reduce it to d^2 = f^2 where d and f are natural numbers?

Comment: @likejiujitsu Yes, and it would have infinitely many solutions: all couples $(a,b)$ with $a=\pm6b$.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut but suppose b = 3*g and a = 3*h. then the equation becomes reduced to 2^2*3*g^2 = h^2. then even though they are natural numbers, the contradiction becomes that a and b factors were not originally removed?

Comment: @likejiujitsu If you suppose $a=3h$ and $b=3g$ in your original equation $3\cdot4b^2=a^2$, then yes, this implies $3\cdot4g^2=h^2$. But you didn't advance much, since it's the same equation. Actually, if $a$ and $b$ have *any* common factor ($3$ or more generally $n$), you can always remove it: $a=nh$ and $b=ng$ implies $3\cdot4g^2=h^2$, same equation. That's why I assumed that $a$ and $b$ have no common factor. If they have any, I remove them, and I still have to solve the same equation, but it's simpler to prove it has no solution: You prove that $3$ must divide $g$ and $h$, contradiction.

Comment: @Jean-ClaudeArbaut thank you both (mathlove and Jean) for your painstaking explanations!  Thank you for your important point above. This is the official proof in the course exercise, however your explanation was most helpful to my understanding so I accept your answer.

Comment: @mathlove I think it is essential to your proof to state that every number is either prime or has a unique prime factorization. Therefore having an uneven number of 3's on lhs and rhs is impossible and contradicts the supposition.

Answer (score 1):

**HINT**

Any perfect square number must contain even powers in its prime factorization :

$$n^2 =  p_1^{e_1}p_2^{e_2}\ldots p_r^{e_r}$$

$$e_i =  2k$$

Answer (score 1):

$3$ is divisible by $3$ and has prime factorization $1 \cdot 3^1$.

Therefore, if $3 = b^2 / c^2$, then the $b^2 / c^2$ is divisible by $3$, and has prime factorization $1 \cdot 3^1$.

Comment: What does this $1$ factor do in the "prime factorization" of $3$? Stating that it's a prime is more than enough, as a square cannot be a prime.

Comment: I agree with the answer that a square cannot be a prime. I think that is the correct proof. However, I am trying to understand why the proof in the Starbird course is not wrong.

Comment: @likejiujitsu The basic idea of this proof is that if $k^2$ is divisible by a prime $p$ it must be divisible by $p^2$. In this case we need to look at $p=3$. The important feature of 12 is that it is divisible by 3 but not $3^2$. I assume that the video you saw was dealing with the classic case of $a^2=2b^2$, In that case we pick $p=2$. If we tried to use this to prove that there are no integral solutions to $a^2=25b^2$ we would fail. It only works for $a^2=Nb^2$ if we can find a prime $p$ for which the highest power dividing $N$ is odd.

Comment: @almagest your comment is helpful in my last comment to mathlove above.

Comment: @Jean-Claude: It's the unit part. Sometimes I have the habit of including the unit part of the factorization even when it's trivial. Note if I was factoring $-3$ I would have written $-1$ in the unit part instead: $(-1) \cdot 3^1$.

Comment: @Hurkyl Ah, ok. Sometimes it's written like this, but neither $1$ nor $-1$ are primes. However, $3$ and $-3$ are primes, so it's a bit confusing. Thanks for the clarification, anyway.